# What Model of classes should I use to generate this Xml structure? (C#)

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I need to create a model that will serialize to an Xml of this form (this is part of a bigger Xml):

```
<ManufacturerPartNumbers>
    <ManufacturerPartNumber>26-12345-8W</ManufacturerPartNumber>
    <ManufacturerPartNumber>26-12345-8Y</ManufacturerPartNumber>
    <ManufacturerPartNumber>26-12345-8Z</ManufacturerPartNumber>
</ManufacturerPartNumbers>
```

I've tried using

```
[XmlType(TypeName = "ManufacturerPartNumber")]
public class ManufacturerPartNumberModel
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

And in the upper class:

```
public List<ManufacturerPartNumberModel> ManufacturerPartNumbers { get; set; }
```

But this generates an extra Xml Node:

```
<ManufacturerPartNumbers>
    <ManufacturerPartNumber>
      <Number>26-12345-8W</Number>
    </ManufacturerPartNumber>
</ManufacturerPartNumbers>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And 5 minutes later I found the answer :)

I just had to add `[XmlTextAttribute]` to the Number property and it will serialize it as a nameless inline attribute inside `ManufacturerPartNumberModel`

```
[XmlType(TypeName = "ManufacturerPartNumber")]
    public class ManufacturerPartNumberModel
    {
        [XmlTextAttribute]
        public string Number { get; set; }
    }
```